# How to connect a LiFePO4 battery directly to an esp32?

Tags: esp32, battery

If I want to connect a LiFePO4 battery (as the power supply) directly to an esp32 - would this be the correct way: the plus of the battery to the 3.3 volt pin and the minus to a ground pin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Absolutely not.

A LiFePO4 battery is 4.2V when fully charged. The absolute maximum voltage of an ESP32 is 3.6V.

You **will** kill the ESP32.

Instead you need to have a voltage regulator with a very low dropout. Ideally a switching ("buck") regulator with a zero-dropout "pass" mode to give the maximum life from your battery.

Even better is a "buck/boost" battery regulator that will boost the voltage up to a stable 3.3V once the battery voltage drops too low.

If all this is beyond you then you're better off using a powerbank to do the regulation to 5V for you then convert that back down to 3.3V with a simple buck regulator.

Comment: The maximum charge voltage is specified [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_iron_phosphate_battery) as 3.65 Volt.

Comment: @sid_com That's the recommended maximum. They can go up to 4.2V if you want about 1% extra capacity. 3.65 is still above the *absolute maximum* of an ESP32 anyway.

Comment: 4.2v is typical of lithium chemistries other than lithium IRON phosphate batteries. One can use a radio control type battery charger and set a maximum charge level to lower than the max for the ESP32. Some capacity may be lost in so doing, but with care, it could be accomplished.

Comment: @fred_dot_u https://www.evworks.com.au/page/technical-information/lifepo4-care-guide-looking-after-your-lithium-batt/#:~:text=Tip%201%3A%20Never%20over%20charge%2Fdischarge%20a%20cell!&text=In%20the%20case%20of%20LiFePO4,3.5V%20and%204.2V.

Comment: from that page: In the case of LiFePO4 chemistry, the absolute maximum is 4.2V per cell, though it is recommended that you charge to 3.5-3.6V per cell, there is less than 1% extra capacity between 3.5V and 4.2V.

Comment: Exactly. Up to 4.2V. If you have that you *will* fry the ESP32. You really really should have a battery controller on there to keep it at a regulated 3.3V regardless of the battery voltage (above the lower cutoff voltage of course).

Comment: The charging voltage for lifepo4 used to be 4.2V but that was killing battery's now it's 3.65V and a fully charged battery is 3.6V which is perfect for the esp32. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/365440/what-is-the-maximum-static-voltage-of-lifepo4-batteries 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_iron_phosphate_battery

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is two years old but it still pops up on research. I just wanted to add something from my experience with this:
If you take an Enerpower HTCFR18650 for example [datasheet](https://enerpower.de/wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Technical-Specifications-HTCFR18650-1800mAh-3.2V-EN.pdf) you see that the maximum voltage isn't 4.2V but 3.65V +/- 0.05V. While this technically is a little bit above the absolute maximum rating of the ESP32 (3.6V), in a non critical environment you can absolutely use the battery without voltage regulator. Just keep in mind that you also will not have any undervoltage protection in this case.

I'm not a fan of this negativity ("**you will fry**", "*you kill you ESP*", "***Everyone will die***"). An ESP32 costs $1. Just try it and if it works its great (it does) and if it doesn't, don't blame me ;)

Comment: You are correct. 3.6V is 100% charge. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/365440/what-is-the-maximum-static-voltage-of-lifepo4-batteries

Comment: Where are you getting your esp32's for $1 please.